# How to display multiple views in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display the following two views in a template `index.html`.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'items/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'popular_items_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.order_by('-rating')[:5]

class tryView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'items/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_items_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
```

Is there a way to combine these two views into one view?

How should I get both query sets displayed on `index.html`?

Is it possible to send all the `Item.objects.all()` and filter in the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few questions here, let me answer the first.

You can overwrite `get_context_data` and add to the context of the template for more items in one view. For example...

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'items/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'popular_items_list'

   def get_queryset(self):
     return Item.objects.order_by('-rating')[:5]

   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context['moreItems'] = Item.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
       return context
```

This way you can include multiple query sets on a page/template as required. In this example `moreItems` would be  available in your template along with `popular_items_list`

In regards to the second question, yes you can pass in the URL arguments and use them to filter the queryset. I suggest reading up on this.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options that I can think of. One option is to [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) in the view, which would looks something as follows:

```
#views.py
class IndexView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'items/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['item_by_rating'] = Item.objects.order_by('-rating')[:5]
        context['item_by_pub_date'] = Item.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
        return context
```

And then in your template you could access {{ items_by_rating }} and {{ items_by_pub_date }}

The second option would be to sort the objects in the template, which would allow you to define just one context variable in your view and then sort in different ways in the template using [the dictsort template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort). This would look something like this:

```
# views.py
class tryView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'items/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.all()

# index.html
{% for i in object_list|dictsort:"item.pub_date" %}
    {{ i.rating }} {{ i.pub_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

I think I like the 2nd option more just passing one object_list context item and then sorting in the template. But either way should be fine.